# Bootstrap Carousel not working with asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm fairly new to asp.net MVC and also Bootstrap. I am trying to get the carousel working on my home page. The carousel is showing on the page and the Image that I have selected as the active image is also showing, but when I click on the indicators or on the prev & next arrows nothing happens. I have checked the css and js files are in the correct folder and they are being rendered on the page so any help would be great.

This is my main _layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />        
        <style>
            body { padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */ }
            .aligntobottom { bottom:0; position:absolute; }
        </style>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Bootstrap")
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Your Logo Here</a>
          </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->          
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="container">

        @if(IsSectionDefined("featured")){
        <div class="jumbotron">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        </div>
        }
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

My Main index page looks like this

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div id="mySlider" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img alt="First slide" src="~/Images/myImg1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="Second slide" src="~/Images/myImg2.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img alt="second slide" src="~/Images/myImg3.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
```

and my bundle config looks like this

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace mmInteriors
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Scripts/Bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Bootstrap").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am probably missing something simple but as with a lot of things sometimes the simple things are the hardest to spot so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The HREF of your left and right Carousel Control is #myCarousel, but the ID of your carousel is myslider

Change with this :

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mySlider" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#mySlider" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: I've changed this but still the same issue :(